# How to handle errors with liveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

In my app, I have this flow:

ClickListender in my fragment:

```
  search_button.setOnClickListener {
        if(search_input.text.isNullOrEmpty())
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Input Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        else
            viewModel.onSearchButtonClicked(search_input.text.toString())
    }
```

`onSearchButtonClicked` inside `viewModel`:

```
    fun onSearchButtonClicked(input: String) {
        coroutineScope.launch {
   repo.insertToDatabase(input)
        }
    }
```

`insertToDatabase` inside `Repository`:

```
   suspend fun insertToDatabase(string: String) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val dataList =
                ExternalApi.retrofitCall.getData(string).await()
            if (dataList.intialDataResult < 1) {
                //show error
            } else {
                //all good
                database.myDataBase.insertAll(dataList)
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to show error message if `intialDataResult` is less then one.
I thought about create `MutableLiveData` inside my repository with initial value of false and listen from the fragment through the `viewModel`, but it's not good approach because I have no way to set the `LiveData` to "false" again after I show error message.

I also tried to return bool from the `insertToDatabase` function and decide if to show error or not, with no success.

Any ideas how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not create a LiveData to manage your work's result state?

Create a class to store result of work <sup>[why sealed class?](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/enum-vs-sealed-class-which-one-to-choose-dc92ce7a4df5)</sup>

```
sealed class ResultState{
    object Success: ResultState() // this is object because I added no params
    data class Failure(val message: String): ResultState()
}
```

Create a LiveData to report this result

```
val stateLiveData = MutableLiveData<ResultState>()
```

Make `insertToDatabase()` return a result

```
suspend fun insertToDatabase(input: String): ResultState {
    return withContext<ResultState>(Dispatchers.IO) {

        val dataList =
            ExternalApi.retrofitCall.getData(string).await()
        if (dataList.intialDataResult < 1) {
            return@withContext ResultState.Failure("Reason of error...")
        } else {
            database.myDataBase.insertAll(dataList)
            return@withContext ResultState.Success
        }
    }
}
```

Now, report result to UI

```
fun onSearchButtonClicked(input: String) {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        val resultState = repo.insertToDatabase(input)
        stateLiveData.value = resultState
    }
}
```

In UI,

```
viewModel.stateLiveData.observe(viewLifeCycleOwner, Observer { state ->

    when (state) {
        is ResultState.Success -> { /* show success in UI */ }
        is ResultState.Failure -> { /* show error in UI with state.message variable */ }
    }
})
```

Similarly, you can add a `ResultState.PROGRESS` to show that a task is running in the UI.

If you have any queries, please add a comment.